# Instantiation of a hidden function

Tags: c++, c++11

Condider the following code:

```
template <class Impl, class Cont>
struct CrtpBase
{
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "Default foo\n";
        Cont cont;
        cont.push_back(10); // Going to fail if Cont::push_back doesn't exist
    }
};

typedef std::unordered_map<int,int> ContType;
struct Child : public CrtpBase<Child, ContType>
{
    typedef CrtpBase<Child, ContType> _Parent;
    // using _Parent::foo // (1)
    void foo() { cout << "Child\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Child obj;
    obj.foo(); // (2)
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm stuck at is conditions when CrtpBase class is instantiated and when it isn't.

At point (2), when I *call* `foo()`, to my point of view, the compiler should generate a list of possible overloads. These are to be `Child::foo()` and `Child::_Parent::foo()`. Therefore `Child::_Parent::foo()` has to be instantiated. (At this point compilation should fail since the error is in the body function, SFINAE not applicable) Then the compiler should choose the priority match.

However the program compiles and shows that `CrtpBase::foo` is not instantiated. The question is why. The compiler somehow knows that `Child::foo` would be the best match and stops overload resolution process.

When I uncomment `// using ...` , asking compiler explicitly to use base function overload to be one of the matches,  nothing changes, it compiles again

**Just to make a sort of conclusion of what I have understood from the answers below as they cover different aspects of what's going on**

1. The compiler doesn't even consider the base overload. That is the crucial fact that I didn't see, hence all the misunderstanding
2. That is not the case here, but choosing the best match during the overload resolution instantiates only the chosen match

Comment: @GillBates Then why uncommenting `using` doesn't cause errors?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you're still hiding `foo()` of the base class. Their signatures are the same.

Comment: @GillBates I don't get it. How the fact of hiding disables instantiation? To find out that the signatures match,the  compiler has to see that there is such a function in the base class. Therefore, it has to instantiate it, no?

Comment: No, the compiler can check function signatures without instantiating the templates here. That's not actually what's happening here though, refer to @Barry's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At point (2), when I call foo(), to my point of view, the compiler should generate a list of possible overloads.

Trueish. We start by looking up the name `foo` in `Child`. We find `Child::foo` and then stop. We only have one candidate, which is a viable candidate, so we call it. We don't continue to look in the base classes, so `CrtpBase::foo` is never considered. This is true regardless of signatures (if `CrtpBase::foo()` took an `int`, `obj.foo(4)` would fail to compile because `Child::foo()` doesn't take an argument - even if a hypothetical call to `CrtpBase::foo(4)` would be well formed).

> When I uncomment `// using ...`, asking compiler explicitly to use base function overload to be one of the matches, nothing changes, it compiles again

That's actually not what you're doing. The *using-declaration* brings the name `CrtpBase::foo` into the scope of `Child`, as if it were declared there. But then the declaration of `void foo()` hides that overload (otherwise the call would be ambiguous). So again, name lookup for `foo` in `Child` finds `Child::foo` and stops. Where this case differs from the previous case is if `CrtpBase::foo()` took *different* arguments, then it *would* be considered (such as my hyptohetical `obj.foo(4)` call in the previous paragraph).

Comment: By the way I've had tried to do that before posting the question. If I change `CtrpBase::foo()` to `CtrpBase::foo(int)` and call `obj.foo(1)` inside `main`, I get 'main.cpp:85:14: error: ‘class std::unordered_map<int, int>’ has no member named ‘push_back’' , so the compiler goes deeper still?

Comment: yes:) , I referred to the first part of your answer. You've said that compilation will fail even if `CrtpBase::foo(4)` is well formed. I'm stating the this is wrong. Sorry if misunderstood you

Comment: @DimG The first paragraph assumes not `using _Parent::foo;`

Comment: Ha, my fault! I thought I had commented it back. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Template classes instances can be instantiated without their methods being instantiated.

`Child` is not a template class instance.  Its methods are always instantiated.

Simply doing overload resolution on a template class instance method name does *not* trigger template class method instantiation.  If it not chosen, it is not instantiated.

This feature originally added in the prehistory of C++.  It permitted `std::vector<T>` to have an `operator<` that would conditionally work depending on if `T` had an `operator<` in the pre-SFINAE era of C++.

For a simpler case:

```
template<class T>
struct hello {
    void foo() { T t{}; t -= 2; }
    void foo(std::string c) { T t{}; t += c; }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9da89320199a3819).

Calling `hello<int>.foo()` considers `hello::foo(std::string)` and does not instantiate it.

Calling `hello<std::string>.foo("world");` considers `hello::foo()` and does not instanitate it.

Comment: thank you, that was really helpful, I didn't know that! However it seems that the base overload isn't even being considered